# Azure API App - Unable to get CORS Working

Tags: azure, cors, azure-api-apps

I am unable to get the CORS option in Azure API App to work. Is this a known Issue?

Chrome throws "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error.

As a workaround I have enabled CORS in the code using System.Web.Http.Cors. However I would like to take advantage of the Azure API App CORS Option.

Comment: Are you able to share related code segment?

Comment: @juvchan I am sorry, i don't understand your question. As far as I know, there is no code required for making the CORS option in Azure to work. Or were you asking me to share the working code ?

Comment: Does this tutorial work for you:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript/

Comment: Got the same issue, can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response but I found a simple way to enable this through the portal:[image: Enable CORS for Azure API Via Portal]